# How do I change the step for Cube metrics?

Tags: cubism.js

I am just starting out with cubism.js

Stripping down the example code I am able to show two metrics .. one calculated (kpi1) -- random function , one from Cube (kpi2). It works perfect at a context step of 1e4 as soon as I change it to 1e3 the calculated one - random - shows fine at a resolution of 1s while the one from Cube does not show at all.

this works:

```
var context = cubism.context()
    .serverDelay(0)
    .clientDelay(0)
    .step(1e4)
    .size(960);
```

this does not:

```
var context = cubism.context()
    .serverDelay(0)
    .clientDelay(0)
    .step(1e3)
    .size(960);
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Dashboard</title>

</head><body><div id="body">


<div id="kpi1"></div>
<div id="kpi2"></div>


<script src="../d3.v2.js"></script>
<script src="../cubism.v1.js"></script>

<script>function random(name) {
  var value = 0,
      values = [],
      i = 0,
      last;
  return context.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {
    start = +start, stop = +stop;
    if (isNaN(last)) last = start;
    while (last < stop) {
      last += step;
      value = Math.max(-10, Math.min(10, value + .8 * Math.random() - .4 + .2 * Math.cos(i += .2)));
      values.push(value);
    }
    callback(null, values = values.slice((start - stop) / step));
  }, name);
}</script>

<script>

var context = cubism.context()
    .serverDelay(0)
    .clientDelay(0)
    .step(1e4)
    .size(960);

var foo = random("foo");
var cube = context.cube();

d3.select("#kpi1").call(function(div) {

   div.selectAll(".horizon")
      .data([foo])
    .enter().append("div")
      .attr("class", "horizon")
      .call(context.horizon());

});

d3.select("#kpi2").call(function(div) {

   div.selectAll(".horizon")
      .data([cube.metric("median(cube_compute(ms))")])
    .enter().append("div")
      .attr("class", "horizon")
      .call(context.horizon());

});

</script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Cubism.js supports any step but the Cube backend system only supports metric aggregation from storage on one of these five steps:

> ```
>   1e4 or 10 seconds
>   6e4 or 1 minute
>   3e5 or 5 minutes
>   36e5 or 1 hour
>   864e5 or 1 day
> ```

If you were to use a step which is between or below these, Cube would not be able to take advantage of the precalculations made at the lower and lowest supported levels, using [pyramidal reducers](https://github.com/square/cube/wiki/Queries#reduces).

Comment: Do you know what factor of performance improvement this provide?